# Can I sync books I didn't buy from Amazon via Kindle app?

Tags: mac, sync, android, kindle

I have the Kindle app both on mac and android, I want to know if it's possible to sync the books that I have on android over to mac and vice versa as well as the last page I viewed? Some books weren't bought from Amazon though. Some of them directly from the seller and is distributed via .mobi file format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can. You will need to send it to your Kindle as a personal document, i.e. email it to your Kindle email address. Once done download it on each device. Notes, highlights and Furthest Page Read will sync between devices.

I use the Android App and a Kindle 4 (Non-touch) and documents handled as per the above work fine and sync without issue.

I did have a problem with one book, but in that case I noted my furthest page read, deleted it from each device, deleted it from the Personal Documents on the Amazon website and then repeated the above process. It then synced perfectly.

One caveat, you cannot sync progress or notes in PDF's

Comment: Note that Kindle currently fails to WhisperSync personal DRM-free ebook sideloads on desktop, making the desktop app basically worthless.

Answer (score 5):

I tried this out. I have Kindle on three devices:

1. PC (Windows 7)
2. Mac (Mac OS X 10.9)
3. Android tablet (4.2)

I'm able to read the emailed .mobi file from my Android tablet. 
I'm NOT able to read it from my Mac :(

In a way this makes sense because the only device that I can assign an email address to is my Android device. This can be done by:

1. Sign in at kindle.amazon.com
2. Choose 'Manage your Kindle' from the dropdown menu
3. Choose the tab 'Your devices'

PC and Mac are not available to be configured with an email address.

If I may say so this is stupidity from Amazon! My question to them is:
Why isn't it enough to just send the .mobi file to one address and have it saved to the kindle service/cloud. And then automatically sync to ALL MY DEVICES?!

Answer (score 3):

No you can't, not with the Kindle for Mac. Only "official" Amazon content will sync to the Mac, rest should be able to sync to handheld devices but you're out of luck on the desktop.
That's Amazon looking after their a**, not yours.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a way. If you put your Kindle folder to a Dropbox folder, you can use the same file in several different places. Then even the non-Amazon PDFs' will sync. I'm using this with my office PC and MacBook, I don't know how it'll work with tablets.

Happy exploring!

Answer (score -1):

Just moved .mobi files from Mac to iPad using AirDrop.
For your Android:

> Use Snapdrop to send files without installing anything
>
> The web-based tool Snapdrop looks a lot like AirDrop for your
>   browser—and I’m surprised Apple hasn’t tried to sue it into oblivion.
>   Nevertheless, if you open the website on different computers or mobile
>   devices (connected to the same network, of course), you’ll be able to
>   drag-and-drop files from one to the other. (I couldn’t get Snapdrop to
>   work on iOS—even in Safari—but had no issues on macOS, Windows, or
>   Android.)