# Transfer Books from Mac to Kindle App on the Nexus 7

Tags: sync, android, ebook, kindle, transfer

I have some e-books that I've downloaded from Project Gutenberg and some other sources to my MBP. They are all DRM free. Excluding e-mail them to my Kindle as a personal document as a method (the total size is more than 5 GB, the space provided by Amazon), is there any way to transfer these books to my Kindle App on my Nexus 7 (Android Tablet). I have the Kindle App version 3.1.7

I've already seen the question [Can I sync books I didn't buy from Amazon via Kindle app?](https://superuser.com/q/434158/14362) but that is not the answer I'm looking for.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

Using Android File Transfer on the Mac (www.android.com/filetransfer/), open the Nexus 7's storage space. In the list of folders, open the /kindle folder and copy .mobi (Kindle reads .mobi and NOT .epub format books). Voila, the books will now show in the Kindle App for the Nexus 7